# Error on MySQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to teach myself MySQL while working on a project at the same time. I'm using phpMyAdmin.

I'm getting the error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ps_category' ('id_category', 'id_parent', 'id_shop_default', 'level_depth', 'nl' at line 1"

My code:

```
INSERT INTO 'ps_category' 
  ('id_category', 'id_parent', 'id_shop_default',
   'level_depth', 'nleft', 'nright', 'active', 
   'date_add', 'date_upd', 'position', 'is_root_category')
  VALUES (6,2,1,0,0,0,1,'2012-04-12 15:12:54','2012-04-12 15:12:54',1,0)
```

UPDATE:

I took off the single quotes and still getting the same error:

```
 INSERT INTO ps_category 
   ('id_category', 'id_parent', 'id_shop_default', 
    'level_depth', 'nleft', 'nright', 'active', 
    'date_add', 'date_upd', 'position', 'is_root_category')
 VALUES (6,2,1,0,0,0,1,'2012-04-12 15:12:54','2012-04-12 15:12:54',1,0)
```

Comment: Don't quote table names - use backticks if you must.

Comment: You should also remove the single quotes from your column names ie `id_category`, `id_parent` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `ps_category` (`id_category`, `id_parent`, `id_shop_default`, `level_depth`, `nleft`, `nright`, `active`, `date_add`, `date_upd`, `position`, `is_root_category`) VALUES (6,2,1,0,0,0,1,'2012-04-12 15:12:54','2012-04-12 15:12:54',1,0)
```

You are using a single quote on the table name. It should be ticks or nothing. It should be noted, the ticks help to ensure properly reading the table name. If you name your table a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), the ticks will prevent it from erroring

Comment: Column names need no single quotes either.

Answer (score 1):

The table name should not be entered as a string literal, either remove these `''` or put two '`' and '`' around it like so

```
 INSERT INTO ps_category ...
```

Or

```
 INSERT INTO `ps_category` ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Table names should not be quoted